# Online-only checking accounts with bill pay and no overdrafting features?

Tags: finance, online-payment

What are some online-only, free checking accounts with bill pay and no overdrafting features, similar to [Simple.com](https://www.simple.com/)*?

<sup>*[Simple.com](https://www.simple.com/) unfortunately is removing bill pay in July 2019.</sup>

Comment: I feel like you aren't asking the right question. I assume if the bank happens to have a physical branch you don't care. I assume if they offer overdrafting features you don't care as long as you have the option to disable them. I'm guessing what you're actually after is a high APY. Is that correct?

Comment: @TTT: On too many accounts, disabled overdrafting is actually more expensive than having the feature enabled.  If enabled, you pay one overdraft fee.  If disabled, you pay a (higher!) returned item fee each time the payee or their bank attempts to present it.

Comment: @BenVoigt - that is certainly true sometimes. Though, I assume since OP specifically doesn't want it, perhaps the alternative is the debit card is declined so that you can't be charged a fee, and you can't go into debt.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ally Bank has free checking accounts with Bill Pay, and OD protection that you can disable.